# showing a function is non decreasing and right continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $F$ is given by

$$ F(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} \chi_{[1/i, \infty)} $$

I want to show that $F$ is non decreasing and right continuous.

So, for non decreasing I assume $y > x $ and I show $F(x) > F(y)$ which is equivalent to $F(x)/F(y) > 1$ but is this always true? what is the best method to show this ?

Comment: Note that non-decreasing means $x<y$ implies $F(x)\le F(y)$, not $F(x)>F(y)$ (which would be a decreasing function).

Comment: What is $\chi_{[1/i, \infty)}$?

Comment: charactehristic function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the function is non-decreasing (I prefer the term *weakly increasing*), this follows from the fact that the sum of weakly increasing functions is weakly increasing, and that $\chi_{[a,\infty)}$ is weakly increasing (since if $x<a\le y$ we have $\chi(x)=0<\chi(y)=1$ and in all the other cases $\chi(x)=\chi(y)$).

Right continuity says that $\lim_{x\to a^+}F(x)=F(a)$. If $x\ne\frac1i$ for some $i$, then there is a neighborhood of $x$ that avoids all $\frac1i$ points, and in this interval $F(x)$ is constant (since none of the $\chi$ functions change value). If $x=\frac1n$, then $F(x)$ is constant on the interval $[\frac1n,\frac1{n-1})$ (or $[1,\infty)$ if $n=1$), and so the limit from the right is equal to the value of the function.